# When I zoom in and out with Google Maps...what function being called?

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, zooming

I have a google map in a UIViewController. When I zoom in and out...what method do I write to access this in iOS Swift? I want to know the current map radius when the user adjusts the view. Would this logic be touchesBegan or does google have a function that I can implement? Is touchesBegan the best method to use if google does not have one? I have something like this right now...but it doesn't work.

```
 var mapRadius: Double {
    get {
        let region = mapView.projection.visibleRegion()
        let verticalDistance = GMSGeometryDistance(region.farLeft, region.nearLeft)
        let horizontalDistance = GMSGeometryDistance(region.farLeft, region.farRight)
        return max(horizontalDistance, verticalDistance)*0.5
    }
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    for touch:AnyObject in touches {
        NSLog("MapRadius: \(mapRadius)");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for. I dont know why this took me so long to find...

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition!) {
            print(position)
}
```